# Ordenar un array asociativo por sus índices en JS

Tags: javascript, array

Me gustaría ordenar un array asociativo por sus índices y la única forma que he encontrado ha sido pasar los índices a un array enumerado, ordenarlos y reconstruir el array asociativo posteriormente.

```
a={
    'Galicia':4,
    'Cantabria':1,
};
// a.sort(); // método no definido para un array asociativo
// paso los índices del array asociativo a uno enumerado
i=0;
c=[];
for(b in a)
    c[i++]=b;
c.sort();   // ahora sí que me permite ordenarlo
// una vez, ordenado, reconstruyo el array asociativo
i=0;
e={};       
for(d in c)
    e[c[d]]=a[c[d]];
console.log(e);
```

¿Existe algún método similar al `ksort()` de php?

Comment: Según tu titulo esto debería ayudarte [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199901/how-to-sort-an-associative-array-by-its-values-in-javascript) (recomiendo la segunda respuesta) si te es de ayuda, lo adjunto como respuesta

Comment: Vamos, que tengo que hacerme una función yo mismo... :) La verdad es que la solución de esa respuesta es mucho más compacta, ¡gracias!

Comment: El concepto de array asociativo no existe en Javascript, a es un simple objeto que funciona de manera similar a un *mapa* y no tiene orden.

Comment: @PabloLozano entonces, ¿no puedo confiar en que, tras aplicar mi algoritmo, ese objeto se quede ordenado? ¿Array asociativo es exclusivo de PHP? Yo intentaba hacer referencia a algo similar a los diccionarios de python o los documentos de mongoDB, ¿no es todo similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los objetos en javascript no tienen un orden para sus propiedades, son un conjunto de parejas clave-valor. Si intentas recorrerlos, el único orden (desde ES2015) es el de inserción (y ni siquiera este orden es totalmente garantizado, pero generalmente funciona).

Una opción es convertir el objeto a un array de entradas y ordenarlo:

```js
let a= {
 clave2: 0,
 clave1: 1,
 clave3: 2,
 clave0: 3
}

for (let clave in a) {
  console.log('La propiedad', clave, 'vale',a[clave]);
}

//array de arrays: [ [clave, valor], [clave, valor], ... ]

let entryArray= Object.entries(a); 
console.log(entryArray.toString());

// Ordenando por clave
entryArray.sort((a,b) => a[0].localeCompare(b[0]));
console.log(entryArray.toString());
//ordenando por valor
entryArray.sort((a,b) => a[1] -b[1]);
console.log(entryArray.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

Tal y como te dice Pablo Lozano y la respuesta de StackOverflow que te pase el concepto de Array asociativo no existe en JS.

Puedes intentar esto y modificar la funcion segun tus requisitos:

```
function getSortedKeys(obj) {
    var keys = keys = Object.keys(obj);
    return keys.sort(function(a,b){return obj[b]-obj[a]});
}
```

Al final lo que haces es transformar el array a un objeto y navegar por el valor de sus propiedades. Esto tipo de ordenacion solo funcionaria si los valor son numericos

Comment: Entonces, mi método es un pelín mejor: pues sí que ordena por las cadenas de texto que utilizo de ¿índices? del objeto, ¿no?

Comment: Ah! Pensa que tu objetivo era ordenar por los números , ordenando las provincias, siendo Cantabria la primera

Comment: Exacto, eso era. Disculpa la confusión, es que el lío de nombres es importante... a saber cómo se llamarán los índices de PHP en JS, ¿claves?

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con este codigo:

```
        miArray.sort(dynamicSort("attr"));

        function dynamicSort(property) {
            var sortOrder = 1;
            if(property[0] === "-") {
                sortOrder = -1;
                property = property.substr(1);
            }
            return function (a,b) {
                if(sortOrder == -1){
                    return b[property].localeCompare(a[property]);
                }else{
                    return a[property].localeCompare(b[property]);
                }        
            }
        }
```

Yo lo hice poniendo en indice como propiedad en el array, y ordenando por este.

Comment: ¿Y cuál es la mejora con respecto a mi propuesta? ¿Es más eficiente?

Comment: Bueno, entro otras cosas, permite ordenar por cualquier propiedad que tenga tu array sea numero o texto